# Flask SocketIO message ack not received

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Flask 2.0.2
Flask-SocketIO 5.1.1

I am trying to build a very simple Flask SocketIO server which sends a message to the client when he connects to the server, and receives the acknowledgement of that message. I am testing my server with [this SocketIO client tool](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/). Sending the message upon connection is working, however my server does not receive the ack of the client. These are my connection and ack method:

```py
def ack():
print('message was received!')


@socketio.on('connect')
def client_connected():
    active_clients.append(request.sid)
    queue.append(request.sid)
    print(request.sid)
    socketio.send("hallo", to=request.sid, callback=ack)
```

So in the client tool, I do receive the message ("hallo"), but on my server it does not print "message was received". Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this client I used did not implement calling the callback function. Implementing a client myself that calls the callback function upon receiving a message solved the issue.